# PostgreSQL Export table .csv as current date

Tags: postgresql

I've need to export my table as .csv file, but the name has to be current date.

Currently I am using

```
COPY public."table" TO 'E:\job.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

What should I do? I tried to look for an answer, but without any luck...

Answer (score 1):

You can always run dynamic SQL

```
DO $func$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE $$
    COPY public."table" TO 'E:\job_$$ || to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY_MM_DD') || $$.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
  $$;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So you're forming the command as a string, and then passing it to `EXECUTE`. This works as `plpgsql`, that you can run either inline, as I've shown, or declared as a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.export_table()
RETURNS VOID AS $func$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE $$
    COPY public."table" TO 'E:\job_$$ || to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY_MM_DD') || $$.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
  $$;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then call it using `SELECT public.export_table()`